# what is the regex for / character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all `/` characters in a string.

What is the regex for that?

```
someString = 'I dont know the name of / in english. :/ ';
anotherString = someString.replace(///g, ')');
```

Comment: For the record, that character is called a [*slash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)).

Comment: There is not anything much more basic in any regexp flavor than how to escape special characters, whether it be the slash or asterisks or dots. I'm confused why you would post a question when google could tell you the answer in 200ms, or any tutorial would tell you (eg, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @torazaburo because Google gets its answer from here and don't recognise if I ask for `regex for /`

Comment: Hmm, now we've moved on recursively to the question of how to formulate google queries or revise ones that aren't working. Sometimes you have to try more than once. Try "regex forward slash javascript".

Comment: @torazaburo I've just done two upvotes of two of your answer after having read your two comments.

Comment: Thanks, let me un-downvote your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to globally replace a forward slash in a JavaScript string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566771/how-to-globally-replace-a-forward-slash-in-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the forward slash to treat it as a literal character. Escaping is done with a backslash.

```
anotherString = someString.replace(/\//g, ')');
```

Comment: +1 Your concise and helpful answer is actually shorter than the comment that recommends the OP to go to Google.  That surely deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
anotherString = someString.replace(/\//g,")")
```

should work. You have to escape the slash.

Answer (score 0):

just escape the `/` with `\`between the regex `//`

```
anotherString = someString.replace(/\//g,")");
```

this `//` is a comment expression in javascript, but I'm sure you already knew that though :)