# replace / with - in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting date like this 09/29/2017 and I want to replace / in - using this in angularjs

```
$scope.newString = $scope.date.replace("/","-");
```

But it generate a date like this 09-29/2017 and doesn't replace whole / to - . How can I replace all / to -

Can anyone help me to get this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to globally replace a forward slash in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566771/how-to-globally-replace-a-forward-slash-in-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular js filter to convert date object according to required format

```
$scope.newString = $filter('date')($scope.date, "MM-dd-yyyy");
```

More about filter please see this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: I know this a suitable answer but when i add this to my code it looks like nothing to display can you explain a little bit about this filter.

Comment: have you inject the filter dependency in your controller ?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this below code:

```
$scope.newString = $scope.date.replace(/\//g,"-");
```

---

### DEMO

```js
var date = "09/29/2017"

var newString = date.replace(/\//g,"-");
alert(newString);
```

Comment: it's return me date like 09/29/2017 not like 09-29-2017

Comment: @user6891871 oops! I have update my answer. kindly get it now

Comment: @user6891871 Please mark as this answer if it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it based on '/' and join it back using '-'

```js
var date = "09/29/2017"

var newString = date.split("/").join("-");
console.log(newString);
```