# Replace string in JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I have a simple JSON on which I would like to replace one string from one property. Let's say this is my JSON :

```
var values = [
    { id: 10, url: "www.mydomainname.com/images\uploads\xfolder\FILE_NAME.JPG", longitude: 121.256248, latitude: 19347774275 },
    { id: 11, url: "www.mydomainname.com/images\uploads\xfolder\FILE_NAME.JPG", longitude: 121.7534025, latitude: 19347868 },
    { id: 12, url: "www.mydomainname.com/images\uploads\xfolder\FILE_NAME.JPG", longitude: 121.85458, latitude: 1934748775 },
    { id: 13, url: "www.mydomainname.com/images\uploads\xfolder\FILE_NAME.JPG", longitude: 121.5525, latitude: 19317868 }
]
```

Now what I would like to do is to replace every `\` with a slash `/` . For example :

from        url: `www.mydomainname.com/images\uploads\xfolder\FILE_NAME.JPG`
to          url: `www.mydomainname.com/images/uploads/xfolder/FILE_NAME.JPG`

What I tried was very simple. This is what I tried :

```
for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var str = values[i].url;
    var res = str.replace("''\''", "/");
}
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated, since it's been a while I've been stucked Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you will have to reassign it

Comment: firslty, that isn't JSON - it's a javascript array of javascript objects

Comment: what is `"''\''"` you'll want a regex for the search value for a start ... `values[i].url = values[i].url.replace(/\\/g, '/')`

Comment: Probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566771/how-to-globally-replace-a-forward-slash-in-a-javascript-string

Comment: no @MatrixTai - that's replacing / not \

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never doing anything with `res` currently. Use a regular expression with a global flag instead:

```js
var values=[{id:10,url:"www.mydomainname.com/images\\uploads\\xfolder\\FILE_NAME.JPG",longitude:121.256248,latitude:19347774275},{id:11,url:"www.mydomainname.com/images\\uploads\\xfolder\\FILE_NAME.JPG",longitude:121.7534025,latitude:19347868},{id:12,url:"www.mydomainname.com/images\\uploads\\xfolder\\FILE_NAME.JPG",longitude:121.85458,latitude:1934748775},{id:13,url:"www.mydomainname.com/images\\uploads\\xfolder\\FILE_NAME.JPG",longitude:121.5525,latitude:19317868}];
values.forEach(value => value.url = value.url.replace(/\\/g, '/'));
console.log(values);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer. It did solve my problem :) @certainperformance

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\\/g, "/");
}
```